# What does # character mean in grep?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

I have a task where it says:

```
grep -n -e "^[[:space:]]" \ 
 -e '#[[:space:]]' $ARG | grep -e include
```

(after the " \ " the code part is on the bottom line)

What does `"#"` mean in the grep line

Comment: As an aside, you should [quotes the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and [avoid uppercase for your private variable names.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

`#` has no special meaning in regular expressions, it's just matching the character literally. So the first `grep` matches lines that begin with whitespace or have whitespace after a `#` character.

They could have used an extended regular expression and matched them both in a single regexp.

```
grep -E -n '(^|#)[[:space:]]' "$ARG" | grep include
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is trivial; like most other characters in regular expressions, it simply matches itself.

The double `-e` is actually more interesting here; you can supply more than one search expression by passing the `-e` option multiple times. (A single `-e` is rarely useful, though it's necessary if you want to pass in a regular expression which would otherwise look like an option to `grep`, like `-n` or, of course, `-e`.)

Comment: You can also use `--` in both GNU and FreeBSD grep